# Getting iframe's src value after dynamically changing it in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, iframe, attributes

After I update an iframe's src attribute using : `document.getElementById('iframe1').src = newsrc` and then attempt to read it: `alert(document.getElementById('iframe1').src);` The src I get is the old source and not the new one that was set. Why is this and how can I get the real current src value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>If the `src` is pointing to a different domain, you can't get it. It's a security feature. I guess IE's way of implementing that security feature is to return the old value for `src`</del>.

Correction: After reading Pekka's comments, I went ahead and tested it. You can try it too at http://jsfiddle.net/pMtZC/ (caution: alerts).

On all browsers I tested it in (Chromium, Firefox 4, IE 8), the changed `src` property was returned just fine. If you set it, it will return the value you set to it. It will not, however, change if the user navigates within the iframe (obviously). What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Almost: The `src` *property* will never change, even if it's a local URL, in any browser I know. It is a plain HTML property. The IFrame's `location` property will change along with the current location but as you say, can't be accessed if it's not on the local domain.

Comment: @Pekka: Neat, never knew that. I guess it's another IE peculiarity to memorize, if I'm ever forced to use iframes again...

Comment: I don't think this is IE specific though. AFAIK, the `src` property doesn't change in any browser - but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Trick it into thinking its not on the local domain.